# Uploading jumbo video files from a PHP page

Tags: php, flash, file-upload, ftp

I am trying to provide a client with a method of sharing video files with members of the media. I'm really not sure how to accomplish this, but there are two things that I'm assuming at this point:

1. To get the 50MB-750MB files on the server I was thinking I'd use a flash control to upload the files like I've seen on other video sharing sites (YouTube, vimeo, ...)
2. This would have to be done via FTP

So I have been searching for a Flash/Java plugin that would help me get these files to the server in a user-friendly fashion, but there doesn't seem to be any open-source options. I'm open to paying for a solution, but not unless it will allow me to use it over and over again. So now I'm thinking I should just setup a public FTP dropbox for admins to put videos using an FTP client like FileZilla, then I can just read the directory and edit/organize/manage the files with PHP.

Does anyone have any insight/help they could share with me? **THANKS!!**

Comment: Why upload the files with a PHP page when you are using FTP?

Comment: I was hoping to use the FTP protocol for uploading the gigantic files so that a user could resume or pause the upload if needed, and also so I didn't have to increase the memory limit for PHP to over 1GB.

Comment: Then you have to write a client application or use applets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of depends on how many people will be uploading the video. If you have a lot of users, then fool proofing it via a UI could be smart, but if it is just a couple of people, then I'd go with the FTP option.

There is no need for a Flash control with FTP as you won;t be affected with timeouts.

Comment: I guess I'm mostly interested in how they do it over at YouTube but that is a good point; It's probably not worth it to implement a custom experience when only a few users will be uploading videos. There are also hundreds of very reliable FTP clients that will get the job done perfectly. Thanks!